# Mathematical formula not giving same answer in C# as in excel, or calculator

Tags: c#, javascript, math, extjs

I have been trying to use a formula that is used to work out exclusive VAT in a program that our team is creating. The formula works correctly when used in a calculator or in excel, though gives a different output when used within a function in our program!

here is the function:

```
function fn_calcVat() 
{
    var vRate = Ext.getCmp('crd_vat_rate').getValue();
    var vTranAmt = Ext.getCmp('crd_tran_amt').getValue();

    if (vRate != '' && vTranAmt != '') 
    {
        alert(Ext.getCmp('vatable').getValue().toString());
        var vAmt = 0;
        if (Ext.getCmp('vatable').getValue().toString() == 'Y')
        {
            vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100) + 1));
            Ext.getCmp('crd_vat_amt').setValue(vAmt.toFixed(2));
            Ext.getCmp('crd_tran_tot').setValue(vTranAmt.toString());
            vAmt = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            vAmt = ((vRate / 100) * vTranAmt);
            Ext.getCmp('crd_vat_amt').setValue(vAmt.toFixed(2));
            Ext.getCmp('crd_tran_tot').setValue((vTranAmt + vAmt));
            vAmt = 0;
        }                
    }
}
```

the problem formula is `vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100) + 1));`

The other formula is working perfectly.

an example input would be 100 with a VAT rate of 14.00, and the expected answer would be a tax amount of 14, though it gives it as 7!!!

We are using a mashup of EXTJS, js and C#...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Nick

Comment: What's the value of Ext.getCmp('vatable').getValue().toString()?

Comment: Wait, isn't 14 / (100/100 + 1) = 7 correct?

Comment: It is either Y or N depending if it is vat inclusive or exclusive...

Comment: @Zach: 7 is correct...he still has integer division problems though

Comment: It's not integer division, if you fix the integer division it's still 7. The formula is incorrect

Comment: as a general rule, you should not store monetary values in floating point types.  Use whatever decimal type your languages/libraries provided.  It's to prevent rounding errors in the conversion between base 10 and base 2.

Comment: From what I can see the answer you have accepted simply made your if and else cases perform the same calculation - what were they meant to be doing differently?

Comment: this is not C#. it's JavaScript. be sure to check the types of variables you're using. "if (vRate != '' && vTranAmt != '')" suggests strings and if that's true then you're in a world of hurt with JavaScript implicit string / number conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is incorrect, it should be

```
vAmt = vTranAmt * (vRate / 100.0d);
```

Comment: Thanks a million... 
that solved it!
Still dunno why it works in excel though!

Comment: You're welcome, I worked with retail software for years, it's amazing what you remember . . .

Comment: This is the formula he had in his else case - what was the if case trying to do?

Comment: Can we also get a 100.0 in the house? Lets not enjoy integer division problems that may creep up depending on language.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably going to falling prey to [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) with the following code:

```
vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100) + 1));
```

You should change the formula to the following to avoid confusion:

```
vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100.0) + 1.0));
```

However, using the numbers you supplied, plugging in 100 for vTranAmt and 14 for vRate won't have a problem with integer division, but will give you 7:

```
vAmt = (14 / ((100 / 100) + 1))
     = (14 / ((1        ) + 1))
     = (14 / (2              ))
     = (7                     )
```

So either your formula is incorrect, or 7 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind.  First, instead of using 'var', use a decimal or something specific.  The reason for this is that the compiler will decide whether you meant integer division or decmial division based on the datatypes of the variables.  If it picks integer, it may be doing some unexpected rounding on your behalf.  Second thing is to make sure that the variable values are all being fetched correctly from those .getCmp() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain:

Formula:

```
vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100) + 1));
```

Parameters:

```
vRate = 14
vTranAmt = 100
```

Substitute:

```
vAmt = (14 / ((100 / 100) + 1));
```

Calculus:

```
vAmt = (14 / (1 + 1));
```

Calculus:

```
vAmt = (14 / (2));
```

Calculus:

```
vAmt = (14 / 2);
```

Calculus:

```
vAmt = (7);
```

So 7 is the expected answer.

But you can rewrite

```
vAmt = 100 * vRate / (vTranAmt + 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it's due to the difference between integers and floating point numbers.

Try it like this:

```
vAmt = (vRate / ((vTranAmt / 100.0) + 1.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the formula is the same in Excel and it works there? I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but the you're dividing by `vTranAmt`, so the bigger this value, the smaller the result. That doesn't sound right, if the result is supposed to be some tax amount...

**Edit:** Most probably you have the `vRate` and `vTranAmt` variables switched.